# Select distinct values and Auto_increment column

Tags: mysql

my table

```
+----+-----+------+
| ID | CID | Year |
+----+-----+------+
|  1 |   1 | 2013 |
|  2 |   2 | 2013 |
|  3 |   2 | 2012 |
|  4 |   1 | 2013 |
|  5 |   3 | 2012 |
|  6 |   3 | 2013 |
|  7 |   1 | 2012 |
+----+-----+------+
```

Here I would like to select Distinct values from the column CID and ID (Auto_Increment) with Year 2013 .
I am using following code

```
select distinct CID,ID from myTable where Year='2013'
```

When I use 'ID' into select query, distinct values are not displaying.

So my final output looks

```
+----+-----+------+
| ID | CID | Year |
+----+-----+------+
|  1 |   1 | 2013 |
|  2 |   2 | 2013 |
|  6 |   3 | 2013 |
+----+-----+------+
```

Fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd959/1

Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your distinct it looks good even the fiddle works as expected, but you could try simply adding year into your distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   cid,
   id,
   Year 
FROM myTable 
WHERE Year='2013'
```

or with group by

```
SELECT 
   cid,
   id,
   Year 
FROM myTable 
WHERE Year='2013'
GROUP BY CID,ID,Year
```

Comment: Have you tested these queries ?

Comment: Tested both in his fiddle he linked

Comment: @voglster, ID must be deleted from the GROUP. Thanks